# use database field in word to query excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, field-codes

`{DATABASE \d "C:\\Users\\Phoenixmoto\\Desktop\\Movies.xlsm" \s "SELECT Title, Genre FROM [Movies$]"}`
This field code delivers a field with serial numbers i.e. FilmId column from Movies excel file Movies sheet, but before invalid merge field dialog box appears and I remove fields.if I use SELECT * it delivers all the fields with correct values.

Comment: Even if I use square brackets to enclose field names no use.

Comment: Did this help? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/word-database-field-code-odbc-connection/d776f63c-530a-4b90-bae0-271822e64efe

Comment: No it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following steps to connect to a Excel file using the database field:

1. Go to "Insert" tab in Ribbon > Click "Quick Parts" dropdown & Choose "Fields"
2. In the Field window that opens, in the "Categories" dropdown, choose "Mail Merge" and the select "Database" from the "Field names"
3. in the right pane, click on "Insert Database" button, which opens a new "Database" window.
4. Click "Get Data" button which lets you select the Excel file in you local.
5. Click "Query Options" which opens a new window. Go to "Select Fields" tab and choose the columns you want from the excel. Click OK.
6. (Optional) Click "Table AutoFormat" to choose a Table Format like Header color, Alternate column etc...
7. Click on "Insert Data" button which opens a new window. Check the "Insert data as field" checkbox.
8. choose "All" records or choose respective records & Click Ok.

That's it. Your data from the excel will be inserted as a table in the word

You can find an example document in the [following zip folder](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4iP2FkkIkGSwp_tzkn_uWT-pbGsxEnF/view?usp=sharing).